# -fx-font-weight has almost no effect on imported fonts in JavaFX css

Tags: java, css, javafx, fonts

I loaded the font into css for 9 different weights, but for some reason only regular and bold work, from the loaded ones: Thin, ExtraLight, Light, Regular, Medium, SemiBold, Bold, ExtraBold and Black. When I specify -fx-font-weight less than 700 then the font is ALWAYS set to Regular, and if more than 700 then the font is ALWAYS set to Bold. The font is called Inter and was downloaded from Google Fonts. The font preview showed that the font thickness is actually different, but JavaFx does not perceive this. What's the matter?

Preview: https://imgur.com/a/RrlzTJQ

Loading font:

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Inter';
    font-weight: 100;
    src: url('Inter-Thin.ttf');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Inter';
    font-weight: 200;
    src: url('Inter-ExtraLight.ttf');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Inter';
    font-weight: 300;
    src: url('Inter-Light.ttf');
}
...
```

Usage:

```css
* { -fx-font-family: "Inter", serif; }

.account-select-add-button {
    -fx-text-fill: #2461FF;
    -fx-font-size: 24px;
    -fx-font-weight: 100; /* almost no effect */
}
```

EDIT:
Removing the font loading code had no effect, since the font was already installed on the system. However, when I remove -fx-font-family the font changes to standard, which means that the font is actually loaded

EDIT 2: [image: Fonts actually have different thicknesses]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Preface**

I stumbled over the information, that the font weights may not work constantly correct in JavaFX. The solution is to not use font weights, but use fonts directly.

**Solution**

FXML-File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ListView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<VBox alignment="CENTER"
      spacing="20.0"
      stylesheets="@hello-view-works-inter.css"
      xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
      xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/18"
      fx:controller="com.example.demo.HelloController">
    <ListView fx:id="listView" layoutX="142.0" layoutY="36.0" prefHeight="238.0" prefWidth="289.0"/>
    <Label fx:id="selection" layoutX="36.0" layoutY="325.0" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="166.0" text="Your selection">
        <font>
            <Font size="17.0"/>
        </font>
    </Label>
    <Label fx:id="labelThin" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="166.0"
           text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.">
    </Label>
    <Label fx:id="labelNormal" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="166.0"
           text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.">
    </Label>
    <Label fx:id="labelBold" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="166.0"
           text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.">
    </Label>
</VBox>
```

CSS file:

```
@font-face{
    -fx-font-family: "Inter Light";
    src: url("fonts/Inter/static/Inter-Light.ttf");
}
@font-face{
    -fx-font-family: "Inter Medium";
    src: url("fonts/Inter/static/Inter-Medium.ttf");
}
@font-face{
    -fx-font-family: "Inter Bold";
    src: url("fonts/Inter/static/Inter-Bold.ttf");
}

*{
    -fx-text-background-color: blue;
}

#labelThin{
    -fx-text-background-color: red;
    -fx-font-size: 48px;
    -fx-font-family: "Inter Light"
    /*-fx-font-weight: 100;*/
}
#labelNormal{
    -fx-text-background-color: red;
    -fx-font-size: 48px;
    -fx-font-family: "Inter Medium"
    /*-fx-font-weight: 500;*/
}

#labelBold{
    -fx-text-background-color: red;
    -fx-font-size: 48px;
    -fx-font-family: "Inter Bold"
    /*-fx-font-weight: 900;*/
}
```

File paths:

[image]

Result:

[image]

**Old**
**Old**
**Old**

The css property `font-weight` controls the stroke thickness of the font in step (100 = thin, 900 = bold).

**BUT:**
Not every font supports all weights from 100 to 900.
Many fonts (if not most fonts) only provide weight 400 for normal and weight 700 for bold.

So if you need the weight 100 for example, but your font does not support the weight 100, you have no chance because this will not work.

**Edit**

This are the font weights of your posted link. Everything normal until 600, 700 and obove is bold.

[image]

Comment: I clarified that I am sure that each file has a different thickness

Comment: You may be wrong. "The font preview showed that the font thickness is actually different". This is not true in your picture. Scroll down the picture and take a look the that "looks" of the font to their according weight.

Comment: Please take a look at my edited answer.

Comment: Do not quite understand. In the picture in the last change I showed the files and their previews. When you open each font file, a window opens showing an example of that font. each file has a different thicknessю The naked eye can see that each of them is different https://imgur.com/a/1NVgRRS

Comment: This is the link you posted first: Preview: https://imgur.com/a/RrlzTJQ .

Can you try the font "Roboto" ?

Comment: "Roboto" reacts the same way. up to 700 - normal, from 700 - thick

Comment: Is the font being loaded? I tried it local. It uses the default font, and the default font only supports 400 and 700 as weight.

Comment: I'm not sure, but it's quite possible. However, I don’t know what might not work in this case (what I did wrong with loading the font)

Comment: Got it to work, check out my edited answer in 2 minutes!

Comment: Could you link to the source of the information you stumbled over.  It sounds correct, but would be nice to have a cross-reference.